# bootstrap navbar toggle opens but does not close

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this react component that renders a header:

```
import React from 'react';

import facebookImage from '../static/images/facebook.svg';
import instagramImage from '../static/images/instagram.svg';
import tiktokImage from '../static/images/tiktok.svg';
import whatsappImage from '../static/images/whatsapp.svg';
import spainImage from '../static/images/spanish.png';

const Header = () => {
  return (
 
<nav className="navbar header_ navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div className="container-fluid">
    
    <div className="navbar-header">

      <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="/images/Full-Color.png" alt="Logo"  className="d-inline-block align-text-top header-logo"/>
      </a>

    </div>

    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li className="nav-item mx-2 active">
          <a className="nav-link header-text" href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item mx-2">
          <a className="nav-link header-text" href="#cars-for-rent">CARS FOR RENT</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item mx-2">
          <a className="nav-link header-text" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item mx-2">
          <a className="nav-link header-text" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link header-text" href="#"><img src={facebookImage} width={"25vw"} /></a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link header-text" href="#"><img src={instagramImage} width={"25vw"} /></a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link header-text" href="#"><img src={tiktokImage} width={"25vw"} /></a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link header-text" href="#"><img src={whatsappImage} width={"25vw"} /></a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div className='d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center'>

      <button className="navbar-toggler  " type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end"></span>
      </button>
      <a className="nav-link header-text mx-2" href="#"><img src={spainImage} width={"25vw"} /></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>



  );
};

export default Header;
```

this is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>APP</title>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing is that the navbar toggler is opening but not closing, I am using bootstrap 5 imported via CDN on my index file I changed the data-toggle to data-bs-toggle and the data-target to data-bs-target as suggested [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#javascript) on breaking changes migrating from 4 to 5 but still does not work, How can I fix this?

Comment: Please see: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/943435)

Comment: thanks for your answer, so that means that bootstrap does not works propperly with react's jsx so I must use that solution you gave me?

Comment: That is not a solution.  It explains how to create a React snippet in your question so that others can more easily reproduce the problem.  However, there is a React version of Bootstrap that you may want to review: [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)